# Reshape a matrix to get a network

Tags: r, social-networking, reshape

I need to reshape a two column matrix into a matrix that is similar to an adjacency matrix.
I have the following dataset:

```
firm_id_1 firm_id_2
1         2
1         4
1         5
2         1
2         3
3         2
3         6
4         1
4         5
5         4
6         3
```

and so on... for 4000 different `firm_id`.

In the first column, there is a direct link between `firm_id_1` and `firm_id_2`. For instance, `firm_id` = 1 is directly linked (first degree) to `firm_id` 2, 4, 5, indirectly linked (to a second degree) to 3 via `firm_id`=2, and indirectly linked to a third degree to `firm_id`=6 via `firm_id`=3, and so on...

I would like to build this matrix in R:

```
firm_id [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]
[1]          1   2   1   1   3
[2]      1       1           2
[3]          1               1
[4]      1
[5]      1
[6]              1
```

Each number represents the degree of separation in the network. Is this doable in R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.edgelist(mat)
shortest.paths(g)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    1    2    1    1    3
# [2,]    1    0    1    2    2    2
# [3,]    2    1    0    3    3    1
# [4,]    1    2    3    0    1    4
# [5,]    1    2    3    1    0    4
# [6,]    3    2    1    4    4    0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Would you have a suggestion as for how I could graph the network for firm_id=1 and all of its linkages and be able to see its direct and indirect connections?